# Taking a constant out of a root

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I came across the following step:

$$\left(\sqrt{\frac{4y^2}{b^4}+\frac{4x^2}{a^4}}\right)^3=8\left(\sqrt{\frac{y^2}{b^4}+\frac{x^2}{a^4}}\right)^3$$

1. Why is it $8$?
2. Is there an algebraic explanation for this process?

Comment: What else than $8$ did you expect ?

Comment: The explanation is that exponents distribute over multiplication for positive reals and $0$. Taking the square root is the same as exponentiation by $\frac{1}{2}$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$\left(\sqrt 4\right)^3=2^3=8.$$

Comment: $(\sqrt{4f(x)})^3=\sqrt{4}^3\sqrt{f(x)}^3=8(\sqrt{f(x)})^3$?

Comment: @gbox $(\forall a,b\in\mathbb R^+)\,\,\,{(ab)}^{\frac{3}{2}}={a}^{\frac{3}{2}}{b}^{\frac{3}{2}}$

Comment: @gbox: what else than $8$ did you expect ?